# Managed server .htaccess redirect to folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am setting up my managed server right now and I have a problem with the `.htaccess` file. I have a few domains pointing to that managed server via a-record setting and on my server I have the `.htaccess` file in the root. Here is how a redirect inside the `.htaccess` looks like in my case:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1
```

All of that works just fine with one exception. If I open the domain in my browser it shows:

http://www.domain.de/folder/

instead of:

http://www.domain.de/

I would like just the domain ending without the `/folder` part to be showing when someone enters the URL, while still showing the content of the `/folder` URL. On top of that I am unsure if this whole thing might have a negative impact when it comes to seo.
Any help would be appreciated.

More information:
My domains are pointing to the server via a-record. When i access the domain through the browser it will show me the root directory of the server. To point it to the subfolder that i have created for the domain ( the one that holds all the files for that domain ) i added the two lines of code to the .htaccess file in the servers root directory. All i want to change now is that if a user opens the website in his or hers browser it should show:
http://www.domain.de
instead of
http://www.domain.de/folder/
I currently have 15 websites pointing to that server and only one of them is working correctly ( this one is based on wordpress ). The wordpress website does exactly what i wanted it to do. I shows the domain ending with .de instead of the subfolder on my server that holds all of the files for that particular domain. Due to the fact that the wordpress version is doing what i want it to do i guess it must be connected to the .htaccess file within the subfolder for that website. So i think all i need is the line in the .htaccess that converts:
http://www.domain.de/folder/ into http://www.domain.de

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue actually. Try a deep reload or clear your browsers cache.

Comment: @arkascha, i thought so too but clearing my cache did not make a difference. I even tryed it from other devices and still have the same result.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but are you trying to redirect *only* people visiting www.domain.de and not http://domain.de?

Comment: @ACE I agree. Currently that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

> If i open the domain in my browser it shows:
>   http://www.domain.de/folder/
>   instead of:
>   
>   http://www.domain.de/

This is happening because this is exactly what you are telling your web server to do...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1
```

The code above is telling the web server "take every visitor to www.domain.de and redirect them to www.domain.de/folder".

> I would like just the domain ending with the top level domain to be showing when someone enters the website.

I believe you musunderstand what a top-level-domain is. Top-level-domain is the `.com`, `.net`, `.org` etc. at the **end** of every URL.

I would recommend using [this](http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/redirect-www-and-no-www/) tutorial to help you further understand .htaccess redirects. Then you can modify what it teaches you to suit your needs...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what a top leve domain is which is why i wrote that i want it to end with the top level domain and not with the folder. I also understand what the two lines of code are doing within the htaccess. My only problem is due to the fact that it is a manged server i can not set it up as a root server. I need to point the domain to that folder and i am trying to figure out a way to point it to the folder without showing the folder at the end.

Comment: So you want www.domain.de to show the contents of www.domain.de/folder without showing it in the URL bar?

Comment: I edited my question and added some more information. I am sorry that it is written that complicated but i dont know how to describe it any better. The bottom line is that i want exactly what you just wrote in your last comment.